# Function Rendering Too Many Times

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

This is an issue that I have encountered many times while working on other projects but could not figure it out then. I hope I have luck this time with some help.

I am using Next.js 12 for this project. The configs are

```
{
  "name": "next12firebase",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.14.0",
    "next": "13.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

I am trying to run a function that only runs after `loading` becomes false. `loading` is set via `useCollectionData`, which is a hook from `react-firebase-hooks`. I want to call a function, fixData, so that it sets the state of a map that I can use later to map through. The code I am presenting now is a bootleg version that has the functions of fixData run whenever `loading` becomes false.

```
export defualt function portfio() {
  ...... 

  const [docs, loading, error] = useCollectionData(q);

        return (
           ......
           {!loading && 
            docs.map((doc) => {
                console.log(doc)
                let tic =  doc.stockTicker
                let data = {
                     shares: doc.shares,
                     price: doc.price,
                     type: doc.type 
                }
                
                let map  = datamap;
                console.log(datamap)
                if(Array.from(datamap.keys).includes(tic) === false) {
                    setDatamap(datamap.set(tic, [data]));
                    console.log(tic + " " + data)
                   
                }
                else {
                    setDatamap((map.get(tic)).push(data))                       
                }
                console.log(datamap)
                
            }
        )}
        ......
)}
```

There's a lot of code missing from here for simplicities sake, but feel free to msg me for any questions on the code. I have tried many different configurations and different versions but i keep getting the same errors, that it's rerendering too many times and that a function cannot be called inside of a react child.

Comment: post all the codes before the return line

Comment: Another error that I get many of the times when trying to run a function conditionally is ```Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.``` I hope that helps with what is wrong.

Comment: Is this code being run inside `useEffect` or `useCallback`?

Comment: @I0_ol I tried running this code inside of a useEffect but it causes the same issues.

Comment: @Dotman It's really hard to help you without seeing more of the code. What I can say is that the code in the `return` statement doesn't look like it's doing anything to render a component. There's a lot of logic in there that you probably want somewhere else. But again, it's very difficult to help with the current information provided. If you share more of your code, I'm sure someone would be happy to try and help you.